# different geometry in SVF and SVF2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have an IFC file that is converted in SVF and SVF2.
We noticed that the same beam has different geometry in both formats ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98mzA.jpg)
The SVF2 geometry is wrong (the beam is rotated or mirrored).
I will send the IFC to  forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com

Answer (score 0):

SVF2 barely reduces the number of geometry instances for this model:
SVF: 18015 geometries
SVF2: 17037 geometries
Since SVF2 loads every geometry individually via a websocket, it takes much longer if the number of instances isn't much smaller compared to SVF.

Add an extra querying string disableWebSocket=true to your website URL e.g. http://localhost:8000?disableWebSocket=true

Comment: In this case the extra time is takes to load SFV2 is not important to us. Correct geomety is. I just tested the same IFC file, the geometry of the beams is stil incorrect! Even if I add the querying string "?disableWebSocket=true", geometry is incorrect!